# Is it possible to serve angular 2+ application directly from file system without server ? In Android or Xamarin WebView?

Tags: android, ios, angular, xamarin, webview

I have this angular 2+ application to be hosted in an IIS or some server. I will be using this application inside a WebView of my Android/Xamarin application. I know we can embed a static html files or serve static html files from Android's file system to Xamarin's webview without hosting it. As it has disadvantages like couldn't offer offline application, I was wondering, if we can server angular 2+ application similar to static html without hosting in a server ? (as in server, for SPA apps we can enable redirect rules to serve index.html in case of http request for routes).

Answer (score 0):

Android emulator provides url to load content at 10.0.2.2:port

So you can run Angular cli server/iis and 
Just load application in emulator with same port number of iis or your webpack